# AutoComplete is not displaying in pre-generated Dynamic Add / Remove Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a dynamic add / remove fields. The first field has an autocomplete option. Everything works perfectly. But there is one problem. Autocomplete is working fine when we add fields but is not working in the fields that are created due to per-inserted values...

Following is my code...

```
<div class="panel panel-default">

  <div class="panel-heading"><center><b>Team Members</b></center></div>

  <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-5"><label>Member's Username</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-5"><label>Role in Project</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>

    </div>

<?php

$project_id = $_SESSION['project_id']; global $wpdb; $member_details = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}_project_members WHERE project_id = %d", $project_id ) );

foreach ( $member_details as $member_detail ) 
{
    $member_username[] = $member_detail->user_name;
    $member_role[] = $member_detail->user_role;
    $member_status[] = $member_detail->status;
}

?>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-5">

        <div class="form-group">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_login[]" value="<?php if ( $member_username[0] != '' ) echo esc_attr( $member_username[0] ); ?>" placeholder="" readonly="readonly">

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5">

        <div class="form-group">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_role[]" value="<?php if ( $member_role[0] != '' ) echo esc_attr( $member_role[0] ); ?>" placeholder="">
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="status[]" value="<?php if ( $member_status[0] != '' ) echo esc_attr( $member_status[0] ); ?>" placeholder="">

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-username-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add</button>

      </div>

    </div>

<div id="username-fields">

<?php $count_usernames = count( $member_username );

for ( $i = 1; $i < $count_usernames; $i++ ) { ?>

<div id="user-fields">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-5">

        <div class="form-group">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_login" name="user_login[]" value="<?php if ( $member_username[$i] != '' ) echo esc_attr( $member_username[$i] ); ?>" placeholder="">

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5">

        <div class="form-group">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_role[]" value="<?php if ( $member_role[$i] != '' ) echo esc_attr( $member_role[$i] ); ?>" placeholder="">
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="status[]" value="<?php if ( $member_status[$i] != '' ) echo esc_attr( $member_status[$i] ); ?>" placeholder="">

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove_field"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</button>

      </div>

    </div>

</div> 

<?php } ?>

</div>

<p class="help-block"><i>To add member please register new User, if already not registered.</i></p>

  </div>

</div>    

<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var wrapper = $("#username-fields");
  var add_button = $("#add-username-fields");

  var x = 1;
  var availableAttributes = [
          "John",
          "Pamela",
          "Rogers",
          "Peter"
        ];
  var previousValue="";

  add_button.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x++;
    var element = $('<div id="user-fields"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_login" name="user_login[]" placeholder=""></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_role[]" placeholder=""><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="status[]" value="Unverified" placeholder=""></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove_field"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</button></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');

    element.fadeIn("slow").find("input[name^='user_login']").autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
      source: availableAttributes,
    });
    wrapper.append(element);

  });

  wrapper.on("keyup","#user_login",function() {
    var isValid = false;
    for (i in availableAttributes) {
        if (availableAttributes[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isValid) {
        this.value = previousValue
    } else {
        previousValue = this.value;
    }

});

  wrapper.on("click", "#remove_field", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function() {
      $(this).closest('#user-fields').remove();
      x--;
    });
  });
});

</script>
```

Please help me to solve my problem... Thanks...

Comment: Please explain exactly which part is not working

Comment: @Sushovan... Autocomplete is not working in the input fields added after this code `<?php $count_usernames = count( $member_username );

for ( $i = 1; $i < $count_usernames; $i++ ) { ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must not be any duplicate ids like **user-fields** and **remove_field** , instead of Id you can use class names.

I have modified you JS and HTML code and replace `id="user-fields" to class="user-fields"`

Please try below code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var wrapper = $("#username-fields");
  var add_button = $("#add-username-fields");

  var x = 1;
  var availableAttributes = [
          "John",
          "Pamela",
          "Rogers",
          "Peter"
        ];
  var previousValue="";

  $(".user_login").autocomplete({
  autoFocus: true,
  source: availableAttributes,
    });
 
  $(".user_login").keyup(function(){
  var isValid = false;
  for (i in availableAttributes) {
   if (availableAttributes[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
    isValid = true;
   }
  }
  if (!isValid) {
   this.value = previousValue
  } else {
   previousValue = this.value;
  }
  });
  
  
  add_button.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x++;
    var element = $('<div class="user-fields"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control user_login"  name="user_login[]" placeholder=""></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_role[]" placeholder=""><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="status[]" value="Unverified" placeholder=""></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove_field" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</button></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');

    element.fadeIn("slow").find("input[name^='user_login']").autocomplete({
  autoFocus: true,
       source: availableAttributes,
    });
    wrapper.append(element);

  });

  wrapper.on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function() {
      $(this).closest('.user-fields').remove();
      x--;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default">

  <div class="panel-heading"><center><b>Team Members</b></center></div>

  <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-5"><label>Member's Username</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-5"><label>Role in Project</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>

    </div>



    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-5">

        <div class="form-group">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_login[]" class="user_login" value="" placeholder="">

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5">

        <div class="form-group">

          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_role[]" value="" placeholder="">
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="status[]" value="" placeholder="">

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-username-fields"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add</button>

      </div>

    </div>

<div id="username-fields">

 <!-- php code start
 
  <php $count_usernames = count( $member_username );

  for ( $i = 1; $i < $count_usernames; $i++ ) { >
 
 -->

 <div class="user-fields">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-5">

   <div class="form-group">

     <input type="text" class="form-control user_login" name="user_login[]" value="10" placeholder="user login">

   </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">

   <div class="form-group">

     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_role[]" value="super" placeholder="">
     <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="status[]" value="active" placeholder="">

   </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove_field" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</button>

    </div>

  </div>

 </div> 

 <!-- php code end
 
  < php } ?>
 -->

</div>

<p class="help-block"><i>To add member please register new User, if already not registered.</i></p>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: +1 Alpesh Jikadra... Great... Thanks... Its working... I have updated part of ur JS code with this `wrapper.on("keyup",".user_login",function() {
    var isValid = false;
    for (i in availableAttributes) {
        if (availableAttributes[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isValid) {
        this.value = previousValue
    } else {
        previousValue = this.value;
    }
    
});` since the code was not working on the newly added fields...